# Real positive number less than one as a series of rationals

Tags: real-analysis

Let $0<x\leq 1$. Prove that there exists a unique sequence $(p_n)$ of integers such that $1<p_1\leq p_2 \leq\cdots$ and $$x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{p_1\dots p_n}.$$

For the existence part I completely lost, can someone give an idea?

For the uniqueness part I'm also stuck but I tried the following. Let $$x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{q_1\dots q_n}$$ be another representation of $x$ such that, for $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for $n< n_0$, $q_n=p_n$ but $p_{n_0}<q_{n_0}$. Then  it must be

$$
\sum_{n_0}^\infty \frac{1}{p_1\dots p_{n_0}\dots p_n} = \sum_{n_0}^\infty \frac{1}{p_1\dots p_{n_0-1}q_{n_0}q_{n_0+1}\dots q_n}. \tag{$*$}
$$

With this I want to deduce the contradiction $x<x$. To do this I compute

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x &= \sum_{n=1}^{n_0-1}\frac{1}{p_1\dots p_n} + \frac{1}{p_1\dots q_{n_0}} + \sum_{n=n_0+1}^\infty\frac{1}{p_1\dots q_{n_0}\dots q_n}\\
&< \sum_{n=1}^{n_0-1}\frac{1}{p_1\dots p_n} + \frac{1}{p_1\dots p_{n_0}}+ \sum_{n=n_0+1}^\infty\frac{1}{p_1\dots q_{n_0}\dots q_n}\\
&< \sum_{n=1}^{n_0-1}\frac{1}{p_1\dots p_n} + \frac{1}{p_1\dots p_{n_0}} -\frac{1}{p_1\dots q_{n_0}} +\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty\frac{1}{p_1\dots p_{n_0}\dots p_n}\\
&= x + \frac{1}{p_1\dots p_{n_0}} -\frac{1}{p_1\dots q_{n_0}},
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where in the second inequality I used $(*)$. Obviously the last part is a number greater than zero $\alpha$, so $x<x+\alpha$. This is the farthest I can get.

Comment: That is known (not so much as it deserves, alas) as [Engel's expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel_expansion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_1$ be the smallest positive integer for which $1/p_1<x.$ Let $x_1 = x,$ and this will be the first term in a sequence of $x\text{s.}$ Then
$$
\require{cancel}
\xcancel{\begin{align}
\frac 1 {p_1} < {} & x \le \frac 1 {p_1-1} \\
& \text{so} \\
0 < x - \frac 1 {p_1} \le {} & \frac 1 {p_1-1} - \frac 1 {p_1} = \frac 1 {p_1(p_1-1)}.
\end{align}}
$$
**The above probably needs further work. See the comments below.**

And so we have
$$
0 < (p_1-1)(p_1x-1) \le 1.
$$
Let $x_2 = \text{this latest number}=(p_1-1)(p_1x-1).$

And now $p_2$ is to $x_2$ as $p_1$ to $x_1$ (and here I'm not talking about a ratio; I just mean $p_2$ is found in the same way).

Just keep going like that. That shows existence.

Comment: How do you ensure $p_1\leq p_2\leq \dots$? Also I get $x = \frac{x_2}{p_1(p_1-1)} + \frac{1}{p_1}$ and since $x_3 = (p_2-1)(x_2p_2-1)$ this implies $x_2=\frac{x_3}{p_2(p_2-1)}+\frac{1}{p_2}$ and $x=\frac{1}{p_1} + \frac{1}{p_2 p_1 (p_1-1)} + \frac{x_3}{p_1 p_2(p_2-1)(p_1-1)}$. I don't get the series.

Comment: Shouldn't be $0<xp_1-1\leq 1/(p_1-1)\leq 1$ with $x_2 = xp_1 -1$?

Answer (score 1):

Idea for uniqueness: Suppose $q_1>p_1$ and

$$\tag 1 \frac{1}{p_1}+ \frac{1}{p_1p_2}+\cdots = \frac{1}{q_1}+ \frac{1}{q_1q_2}+\cdots.$$

The right side of $(1)$ is then no more than

$$\frac{1}{q_1}+ \frac{1}{q_1^2}+\frac{1}{q_1^3}+\cdots = \frac{1}{q_1-1} \le \frac{1}{p_1}$$

But the left side of $(1)$ is greater than $\dfrac{1}{p_1},$ contradiction. So $q_1>p_1$ is impossible, and by symmetry so is $p_1>q_1.$ Thus $p_1=q_1.$

Possible lather, rinse, repeat scenario.